# Javascript custom array prototype

Tags: javascript

I have for example this multidimensional array:

```
MyArray[('A', 40, true), ('B', 20, false), ('C', 55, true), ('D', 17, true)]
```

and I'd like to implement a custom min() and max() prototype to get min and max only of thoses are 'true'... any trick? I'm stuck at it since I was thinking around .map() to extract a certain property but how to check if enabled to extract due of true/false property.

---

Precisely, I did:

```
var MyArray = [];

MyArray.push( {
   name: 'A',
   valueA: 40,
   valueB: 36,
   enabled: true
});

MyArray.push( {
   name: 'B',
   valueA: 20,
   valueB: 18,
   enabled: false
});

MyArray.push( {
   name: 'C',
   valueA: 55,
   valueB: 75,
   enabled: true
});

.
.
.
```

that's why I am looking for the max and min of ones that are with state true, excluding the ones that are false...

I tried to implement:

```
Array.minElement = function(array, prop) {
    return Math.min.apply(Math,
                array.filter(function(arr) { return arr['enabled']; })
                     .map(function(arr) { return arr[prop]; })
           );
}

Array.maxElement = function(array, prop) {
    return Math.max.apply(Math,
                array.filter(function(arr) { return arr['enabled']; })
                     .map(function(arr) { return arr[prop]; })
           );
}
```

so I should call like Array.minElement(MyArray, 'valueA') to obtain the minimum but looks like it doesn't work....and it should return the min...

what I did wrong here?...

Thanks at all
Cheers
Luigi

Comment: Show us what you've tried

Comment: You probably mean `[['A',40,true],['B',20,false]...`. In the current form, it's an array of four booleans.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried, and your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end I re-implemented minElement and maxElement like this:

```
Array.minElement = function(array, prop) {
    var lowest = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    for (var i=array.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        if (parseFloat(array[i][prop]) < lowest) lowest = parseFloat(array[i][prop]);
    }
    return lowest;
}

Array.maxElement = function(array, prop) {
    var highest = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
    for (var i=array.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        if (parseFloat(array[i][prop]) > highest) highest = parseFloat(array[i][prop]);
    }       
    return highest;
}
```

and now it works well

Answer (score 1):

If `MyArray` looks like:

```
var MyArray = [['A', 40, true], ['B', 20, false], ['C', 55, true], ['D', 17, true]]
```

I’d do a combination of `filter` and `map` to get the array, then apply a `Math` method:

```
Math.max.apply(Math, 
    MyArray.filter(function(arr) { return arr[2]; })
           .map(function(arr) { return arr[1]; })
); // => 55
```

Answer (score 0):

[Arrays cannot really be extended](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array) but here's an example.

```
var createSpecialArray = (function () {

    function max() {
        return this.reduce(function (maxVal, item) {
            var val = item[1];

            return item[2]? 
                ((maxVal === null || maxVal < val)? val : maxVal) : 
                maxVal;
        }, null);
    }

    return function createSpecialArray() {
        var arr = Array.apply([], arguments);

        arr.max = max;

        return arr;
    };

})();
```

Then you can do something like:

```
var myArray = createSpecialArray(['A', 40, true], ['B', 20, false], ['C', 55, true], ['D', 17, true]);

console.log(myArray.max()); //55
```